# How to check if a javascript string is between two other strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I had a string like so:

```
let string = "one two three four five red five six seven eight nine"
```

How could I return a boolean (either `true` or `false`) that tells the user if the word `red` is between the two words `five` (In this case a boolean of `true` would be returned as `red` is between the two `fives`)?

> Example where I am using this code

I am making a text editor where the user types code in a text area.

I am going to return the value of the text editor as a variable. I would like to check if the user is inputting code within two `<script>` tags.

Here is the code for the `textarea`:

```
<textarea class="form-control slideIn" id="input" spellcheck="false" wrap="off" placeholder="Get Creative!"></textarea>
```

And this code gets the value of the `textarea`:

```
const code = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

Does this help?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: Share the code that you have tried

Comment: First of, how would you define which world you're going to search and the word to use in between?

Comment: `var s = "one two three four five red five six seven eight nine";
     var matched = s.match(/(?<=five\s+).*?(?=\s+five)/gs);
     console.log(matched);`

Comment: s.match("five.*red.*six")

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a simple regex like this one `five(.*)five`

With a bit of configuration, it could become something like

```
function isBetween(mystring, between, left, right)
{
    // define the regex which will become : "/five(.*)five/g"
    const regex = new RegExp( left + ' (.*) ' + right, 'g');

    // execute the regex
    const m = regex.exec(mystring);

    // if there is a result and the (.*) pattern matched sthg
    // then check if its equel to red
    return m && m[1] ? (m[1] === between) : false;
}

isBetween("one two three four five red five six seven eight nine", "red", "five", "five");
```